# Most useful public recommendation engine

Tags: webapp-rec

By recommendation engine, I mean a web app where you tell it your favourite things, and it recommends other things that you might like, based on a corpus of data.

Apparently Netflix does this for movies (I don't know, I live outside the US).

I've used these in the past for:

- movies
- books
- games
- music
- etc

...but it looks like they've all since disappeared (kindakarma, wikilens, a few others I think).

Can you save me (and future generations arriving here by google!) some hours of searching and **recommend any good recommendation engine web apps**?

Particularly looking for video games, but any will do.

Comment: Amazon is not directly a recommendation engine, but it works quite well if you just tell it what you like (and it should work for everything you listed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might give [Hunch](http://hunch.com/help/) a try. It asks you questions about what you like and gives you recommendations. Backed by fancy-schmancy machine learning algos and web-2.0-tastic team (like Caterina Fake, co-founder of Flickr), it may be an interesting option.

Comment: This was kind of fun, and seemed to have a lot of categories.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same query not too long ago...

I came up with:

- [abetteropinion.com](http://abetteropinion.com)

Secondly if you are looking for game recommendations/similar games based on your input of favorites, here are some great sites:

- [playfire.com](http://playfire.com)
- [raptr.com](http://raptr.com)
- [www.gamerdna.com](http://www.gamerdna.com)
- [www.xfire.com](http://www.xfire.com)

For more raw data/recommendation engine kind of information:

- [www.freebase.com](http://www.freebase.com) A wealth of free data
- [www.trustedopinion.com](http://www.trustedopinion.com)
- [lucene.apache.org/mahout](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout) - Engine for recommendation, clustering and classification.

Comment: abetteropinion had a clunky interface and some questionable recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GetGlue](http://getglue.com/). It has some nice browser integration and is available in a lot of platforms. As far as I know it serves as a recommendation engine for everything you mentioned, and is reported to be growing a lot, which should mean that the quality of the recommendations should be high.

**EDIT:** I just stumbled upon this [blog post](http://www.online-college-blog.com/features/100-recommendation-engines-for-great-discoveries-and-saving-time/) with quite a big list of recommendation engine apps, organized by type.

Answer (score 0):

Colleagues from mine recently launched a new service called **tagmantic**, which as its core supports a tag2tag and tag2uri recommendation engine, if you want to give it a try (it is still in beta stage) at:

- http://www.tagmantic.com

For initial population, you can upload your local or delicious bookmark collection, and might want to give the bookmarklet a try in your daily usage.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your listening charts (the bigger the better), [last.fm](http://lastfm.com/) can come up with interesting albums/concerts recommendations